# Why am i getting a unhashable type error

Tags: python, input, split, store, words

I am trying to find all matching words from both input files but I keep getting  "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'". I have no idea why. Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#First file
file = raw_input("Please enter the name of the first file: ")

store = open(file)

new = store.read()

#Second file
file2 = raw_input("Please enter the name of the second file: ")

store2 = open(file2)

new = store2.read()

words = set(line.strip() for line in new)

for line in new:
    word2 = line.split()
    if word2 in words:
            print words
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` exception because `word2 = line.split()` is returning a list object.
And you are trying to search for list(unhashable object) in your `words` set object.

For example:

```
>>> word2 = 'abc'
>>>
>>> word2.split() in set(['abc', 'def'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

`split` is not the right function here. You should use `strip` function to remove the `whitespaces`.

```
>>> word2.strip() in set(['abc', 'def'])
True
```

Comment: When I do it this way, I am getting all the matching letters. I need all the matching words

Comment: Can you add a sample case of what you are facing ?

Comment: I get back a bunch of lines like this "set(['', '"', ',', '.', '?', 'A', 'I', 'M', 'W', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'h', 'k', 'm', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'p', 's', 'r', 'u', 't', 'w', 'v', 'y'])"

Comment: I need it to return all the matching words such as "apple" "away" etc

Comment: This is because of `words = set(line.strip() for line in new)`. Here your `new` object is returning you the whole file content and when you are iterating it, it is iterating over each character. You should iterate it line by line and split them by space and append it in some list.
And finally call the `set` function on that list.